# How to capitalize word (i.e. first letter to upper) in KornShell

Tags: ksh, string

Is there a builtin way in KornShell to capitalize a word, e.g. `korn` -> `Korn`? A Bash 4 example to clarify:

```
str='korn'
echo "${str^}"
```

If there is not a bultin way to do this in KornShell, what is the most concise and efficient way to write a function that will do it?

Comment: bash can do this with `M-c` (typically, `Alt-c`) at the beginning of the word.  No idea about ksh though.

Comment: @Kazark, better specify whether you want editing or scripting functionality. My understanding was that you want something like `str='korn'; echo "${str^}"` in `bash`. But after @jw013's comment I am not so sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pure ksh (ksh93) way:

```
function cap {
    typeset -u f
    f=${1:0:1}
    printf "%s%s\n" "$f" "${1:1}"
}

$ cap korn
Korn
```

Comment: Not excessively verbose. +1 ...I didn't know the syntax for string slicing, so that is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have ksh93 available, you can do it in standard ksh like this:

```
function capitalize { 
  typeset -u first
  first=${1%"${1#?}"}
  print "${first}${1#?}"

}
```

`${1#?}` strips all characters matching "?" from the beginning of the first arg.  i.e. strips off the first character

`${var%pattern}` strips off `pattern` from the end of `var`.  If we use the original word minus the first letter as the pattern (`${1#?}`), we get the first letter back.

typeset -u turns the first letter uppercase

```
$ capitalize "the funky chicken"
The funky chicken
```

Caveat, this actually doesn't always work since you could have special regex characters after the first letter of the word and they will be interpreted as such by `${var%pattern}`.  e.g.

```
$ capitalize a*
A**
```

Comment: you might want `print -- ...`. I can't recall how `ksh`'s print handles `-o`ptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
% str='korn'
% echo ${(U)str:0:1}${str#?} 
Korn
```